# Sizing images within grids, and alignment with other sections

Tags: html, css

Also, I don't understand how I can resize images withing columns, ive tried many methods people have told me to use, but none have worked. I have yet to find a solution. I'm trying to make the images smaller in each grid area. Yet if I manually set a pixel width to something nothing changes. Does it require I change the width of the grid area? I'm confused because I am following a tutorial where the images are the same size that I am using and the css settings are the same as mine but I get much larger images that wont change in size. I understand that to flip them i need to use order: -1 that isnt the problem, its just the sizing.

[current layout of my page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXpFX.jpg)

[current layout of mine 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awntz.jpg)

what im trying to achieve is this...

[for small screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjcFr.png)
[for big screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytihh.jpg)

```
<section class="about">
  <div class="grid-container">
<article class="about-container">
    <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae!
            Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, libero ex sit ut dolores veritatis nemo voluptatibus, sequi quasi temporibus magni, accusantium labore delectus? A accusamus provident ut ipsa libero.</p>
      </div>
<div class="about_image">
    <img src="img/bravo.jpg" class="about__img" alt="about-img">
</div>
</article><!--about column 1-->

<article class="about-container">
    <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae!
          Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia, cumque atque itaque eaque, ipsam ducimus aliquid vitae deserunt?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_image">
          <img src="img/bravo.jpg" class="about__img" alt="about-img">
      </div>
</article>
</div><!--grid container-->
</section>
```

```
.about_img{
    display: block;
}

.grid-container{
    max-width: 90vw;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .grid-container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-column-gap: 4rem;
    }
}

.grid-container{
    max-width: 75vw;

}

.title{
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.title_name{
    font-size: 3em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.title_underline{
   background: #F4D06F;
width: 5rem;
height: 0.25rem;
}

.title_text{
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    color: grey;
}

.about-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2rem;

}
```

Comment: To make an image fit the width of it's parent responsively you need to apply this CSS to the images: `max-width:100%;height:auto;`

Comment: but the issue is i dont want the images to appear so large, id like them to be smaller. Do I need to change the image properties size prior to adding them to the html?